# Interpret infinity in a knapsack task

Tags: java, algorithm, knapsack-problem

We have a algorithm with a recursive formula,for a knapsack problem with asymptotic O((n^2)*Vmax),where n - count of items,Vmax - max of Values  :
A[i,x] - min total size needed to achieve value >= x , while using only the first i items.
A[i,x] = min{A[i-1,x] , A[i-1][x-v[i]]+w[i]}, where A[i-1][x-v[i]] = 0 if v[i]>=x;Base case : A[0,x] = 0 if x == 0  and plus inf. otherwise;

For a +inf. in java I use a Integer.Max_VALUE. When algorithms run there is a call : A[0,1] , A[0,2] ... And matrix filled negative numbers (int overflow) 
How I can to inеterpretet infinity and infinity plus number?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not storing infinity nowhere, and use it just for comparison, you can use double infinity, which is larger than int and long max value.

```
Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY
```

if you are storing the numbers, and you still overflow you should store the numbers as long in the array, and compare then to integer max value, this way you will know the number is bigger than your max value without overflowing. The cons of this are, slower execution and bigger memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum value of your input, try with a value slightly larger than that value. That should do the trick.